# Which Hypothesis Test for AB test with 4 variants

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, ab-test

**Disclosure**: Stat noob trying to understand the basics of ab testing

**Context:** I'm running an AB test with 3 treatment test to see which one yields the highest click thru rate.

**Q**: What is the recommend hypothesis test for this experiment.

**Option 1)** t-test which tests equality between the  control and one variant for each pair: control-variant1 , control-variant2, control-variant3

**Option 2)** ANOVA test which will test for equality among all variants.

**Option 3)** Both t test and anova? Not sure that makes sense but just wondering if some have ever done that. Let's say I run a t test between control and variant 1 and determine statistical significance for p < 0.05 then automatically running an ANOVA test should yield the same conclusion since at least one variant being different allows to reject the NULL hypothesis

**Option 4)** Any other ????

Comment: What hypothesis or hypotheses do you want to test? In other words, what questions do you want to answer?

Comment: @Dave Which variant is performing the best